# Disable the ':' character in Vim

Tags: vim

In my `~/.vimrc` I have mapped `;` to `:` so I don't have to press shift every time I want to enter a command and so I avoid typos like `:W`. I have mapped it using `nnoremap ; :`. My muscle memory is so strong however, is that I find myself frequently pressing `:` when I dont need to and I still get typos like `:W`.

How can I disable the `:` character completely and just use `;` in normal mode?

Comment: Can you remap `:` to something harmless?

Comment: @KeithThompson: What is considered "harmless" and would doing that have any serious side effects? Which remapping command would I use?

Comment: PS. just thought of this: apparently you don't ever use `;` and `,` much? These are really underrated commands in vim!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : <nop>
```

would be considered fairly harmless.

<sub>*I don't need to point out that using this kind of setup will drive anyone trying to use your box nuts, and will render yourself crippled when at a random other UNIX console :)*?...</sub>

Comment: I'm not going to do it permanently, but I want to re-wire my muscle memory when using my vim setup.

Comment: Good strategy. It is probably how i would force myself to do it. Meanwhile `map <up> <nop>`, `map <down> <nop>` etc... [were mentioned yesterday on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614546/vim-cursorline-color-change-in-insert-mode)

Comment: Instead of `<nop>`-ing the `:` key, one can just swap the `:` and `;` commands, `:nnoremap : ;`, `:nnoremap ; :`, so that semantics of useful `;` command would not be lost.

Comment: @ib: +1 Although, one would argue that `<nop>` is the more harmless (albeit slightly less useful) option

Comment: @sehe:  The only "harm" the `;` command could cause is changing position of the cursor inside the current line.

Comment: @ib: I know. I was joking ... You got the +1 up front :)

Comment: One should note that this does break a thing or two. If you have nmap like <Leader>u :GundoToggle, they will stop working.

Comment: @ZameerManji: nope, that is a broken mapping. If it needs the original behaviour it should have been using `nnoremap`  anyway. Also, @all: these comments really should go with the question. _I, in no way, do endorse this mapping. I'm just answering questions here_ So..... if you can all please move you skeptic comments right with next to ... you guessed it: mine :) Thank you very much

Comment: @sehe:  Absolutely agree with your last comment! :-)